# How to get Target namespace for SOAP non-wsdl webservice

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

How do you get the URI for using the SOAPClient which doesn't have the WSDL. The user has not provided us with the WSDL, but wanted to use their webservice using SOAP to get some information. I am looking for how to do it on PHP.
The confusion part is how to identify the URI value (target namespace). Based on their documentation,below is the sample they provided for SOAP call to me made.

The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

````
**POST /webservices/wssamples/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.samplecomponents.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length**

```

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <QueryAvailability xmlns="http://www.samplecomponents.com/webservices/">
          <program_id>string</program_id>
          <security_id>string</security_id>
          <part_number>string</part_number>
        </QueryAvailability>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>

```

**RESPONSE**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <QueryAvailabilityResponse xmlns="http://www.samplecomponents.com/webservices/">
          <QueryAvailabilityResult xmlns="http://www.samplecomponents.com/schemas/sample_availability.xsd">
            <timestamp>dateTime</timestamp>
            <item_count>unsignedInt</item_count>
            <items>
              <item>
                <part_id>unsignedInt</part_id>
                <manufacturer_part_number>string</manufacturer_part_number>
                <stock_source>string</stock_source>
                <digikey_part_number>string</digikey_part_number>
                <description>string</description>
                <quantity_available>unsignedInt</quantity_available>
                <break_quantity>unsignedInt</break_quantity>
                <rohs_compliant>bytes</rohs_compliant>
                <flag_non_stock>boolean</flag_non_stock>
                <flag_obsolete>boolean</flag_obsolete>
                <flag_static_sensitive>boolean</flag_static_sensitive>
              </item>
              <item>
                <part_id>unsignedInt</part_id>
                <manufacturer_part_number>string</manufacturer_part_number>
                <stock_source>string</stock_source>
                <digikey_part_number>string</digikey_part_number>
                <description>string</description>
                <quantity_available>unsignedInt</quantity_available>
                <break_quantity>unsignedInt</break_quantity>
                <rohs_compliant>bytes</rohs_compliant>
                <flag_non_stock>boolean</flag_non_stock>
                <flag_obsolete>boolean</flag_obsolete>
                <flag_static_sensitive>boolean</flag_static_sensitive>
              </item>
            </items>
          </QueryAvailabilityResult>
        </QueryAvailabilityResponse>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>


**HTTP POST**
The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /webservices/wssamples/service.asmx/QueryAvailability HTTP/1.1
Host: www.samplecomponents.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length
program_id=string&security_id=string&part_number=string```

**RESPONSE**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <sample_availability xmlns="http://www.samplecomponents.com/schemas/sample_availability.xsd">
      <timestamp>dateTime</timestamp>
      <item_count>unsignedInt</item_count>
      <items>
        <item>
          <part_id>unsignedInt</part_id>
          <manufacturer_part_number>string</manufacturer_part_number>
          <stock_source>string</stock_source>
          <digikey_part_number>string</digikey_part_number>
          <description>string</description>
          <quantity_available>unsignedInt</quantity_available>
          <break_quantity>unsignedInt</break_quantity>
          <rohs_compliant>bytes</rohs_compliant>
          <flag_non_stock>boolean</flag_non_stock>
          <flag_obsolete>boolean</flag_obsolete>
          <flag_static_sensitive>boolean</flag_static_sensitive>
        </item>
        <item>
          <part_id>unsignedInt</part_id>
          <manufacturer_part_number>string</manufacturer_part_number>
          <stock_source>string</stock_source>
          <digikey_part_number>string</digikey_part_number>
          <description>string</description>
          <quantity_available>unsignedInt</quantity_available>
          <break_quantity>unsignedInt</break_quantity>
          <rohs_compliant>bytes</rohs_compliant>
          <flag_non_stock>boolean</flag_non_stock>
          <flag_obsolete>boolean</flag_obsolete>
          <flag_static_sensitive>boolean</flag_static_sensitive>
        </item>
      </items>
    </sample_availability>


These is no reference to URI or target namespace to be supplied on this documentation. Any help much appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0):

The "target namespace" is simply the XML namespaces of the element inside the SOAP body - in this case the `QueryAvailability` and `QueryAvailabilityResponse` elements which would be the root of the document if all the SOAP wrapping wasn't there.

So you just need to read the `xmlns` attributes in the sample, which show those elements to be in the namespace `http://www.samplecomponents.com/webservices/`

Comment: Got it. So in this case, it would be something like

`$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
            'location' => "http://www.samplecomponents.com/webservices/QueryAvailability",
            'uri'      => "http://www.samplecomponents.com/webservices/",
            'trace'    => TRUE
          )
       );`